# Facebook login, redirect_uri is not owned by the application. why?

Tags: facebook

I can't add FB login to my site. I simply registered the application:

```
URL: http://www.chusmix.com/
DOMAIN: www.chusmix.com
```

And then I pasted the login code and replaced my APP id in it:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'212044715486306', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
      <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
  </body>
</html>
```

However when clicking the login button I get `Error 191: redirect_uri is not owned by the application`

Also this code is in the page: http://www.chusmix.com/game/ according to what Facebook says filling the field DOMAIN makes all pages in the domain able to use Facebook Authorization. However I also tried pointing directly to the domain where the Login Button is and I get the same error.

There isn't even a redirect url.

---

**Update:** It seems the Login works in http://www.chusmix.com/game/ but doesn't on http://chusmix.com/game/ (without www).

Is there a way to make it work if the user doesn't type www.? Or do I have to use a redirect?

Comment: The http://www.chusmix.com/game/ login does not throw any errors when I try to login. So where and when exactly does the problem appear? If you change the URL in your app settings it may take a few minutes until the settings are saved on all facebook servers!

Comment: Thank, I just realized it's doesn't work if you don't type www. Is there a way to make it work in both cases?
http://chusmix.com/game/ isn't working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding the site URL to the app settings Edit Settings->Web Site->Site URL.  While you are there you might as well fill in the Site Domain in case you add sub domains in the future.

Comment: I just realized: http://www.chusmix.com/game/ works but http://chusmix.com/game/ doesn't. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try setting Site Domain as suggested above.  Set it exactly to "chusmix.com" with nothing in front.  I would also set Site URL to `http://chusmix.com` and the www should work as a sub domain.

Comment: Yes it did. It started working properly after some time of leaving it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this as you `Site Domain: chusmix.com`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure every URL in your JS script matches EXACTLY to the Site URL you set up in Facebook, including `http://`.

**Ex:**

```js
 FB.init({
      appId      : '128957350986', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'zazzlebaytobreakers.com/lib/channel.php', // Channel File
```

Will cause this error in IE 7 and 8.

**Make sure it's:**

```js
 FB.init({
      appId      : '128957350986', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'http://zazzlebaytobreakers.com/lib/channel.php', // Channel File
```