# "redirect_uri is not owned by the application" when adding Facebook app

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add a Facebook tab to a page using the url:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=256000XXXXXXX&display=popup&next=https://www.facebook.com/mypage

But I'm getting the error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

In my settings All the URLs are correct, including the App Domains.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook login, redirect_uri is not owned by the application. why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835014/facebook-login-redirect-uri-is-not-owned-by-the-application-why)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API error 191](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook must have changed something because using the url 'https://www.facebook.com/mypage' no longer works. I instead needed to use 'https://www.facebook.com'.